# What is the answer to the squirrel and the yellow hat riddle?

Tags: candy-box-2

"Under a full moon, I throw a yellow hat into the red sea. What happens to the yellow hat?"

I don't get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is rather easy.

What would happen to a hat you throw into the sea?

The hat

> floats

Answer (score 3):

> Wet

Also Works as an appropriate answer

Answer (score 0):

Another correct answer is:

> "It gets wet"